# Using an ImageAdapter with a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, baseadapter

I am trying to use a custom image adapter in conjuction with `GridView` and a `fragment`.  When I use virtually the same code with just an `Activity` the code works fine.  But When I use a `fragment` the images no longer show up.   Below is the relevant code

**Note:** thumbnails is a global variable of my fragment class

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    GridView gridView = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_grid);
    thumbnails = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
    gridView.setAdapter(thumbnails);
    return rootView;
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    private Integer[] mThumbIds ={
            R.drawable.test,
            R.drawable.test2
    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 0; //FOR NOW
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        //test with drawable folder
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        return imageView;
    }



}
```

and my layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ghanghan.popularmovies.MoviesFragment">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center">

    </GridView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

look your `getCount()` . It should return 2.

```
 public int getCount() {
        return 0; //FOR NOW
    }
```

Comment: Welcome . You can accept my answer if it is useful.